# Unexplainable "Target container is not a DOM element" on render() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following error when trying to render simple html into my footer:

> _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM e

lement.

My render() is written just like other working ones in the same document, as following:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Footer />, document.getElementById('app-footer'));
```

My footer.js from which i export the Footer class looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
class Footer extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               <h3>Testtext</h3>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Footer;
```

I have tried multiple solutions already given here but none seem to work for this seemingly easy problem. I tried putting a document.onload around it, but that did not work. I really hope someone can point out the flaw in this one.

Comment: Where is your `#app-footer`?

Comment: Do you have an HTML element with the ID `app-footer`?

Comment: How does your html look like? Also, is it part of a section into which you are already rendering something through react (where React would rather replace the content)

Comment: @elclanrs My html is quite simple actually, its a body containing, app-header, app-content, app-footer

Comment: @kqcef Yes, just like the other working elements.

Comment: @Icepickle My html is quite simple as i said in my comment above. And no, it's the only thing i'm doing with that element. I render all 3 elements though.

Comment: Since 3 persons ask for it, it might not be that bad to update your question with an MCVE

Comment: Is there actually a reason for not using React to render the header, content and footer? Any reason why you choose to render all 3 separately? I can imagine once you come to a situation where you have to reload based on state/prop changes that you would be reinventing the wheel from there on

Comment: @Icepickle As i am relatively new to React, my i thought it would be better for performance to update separate parts of a page instead of the whole page. And as this was just a playground for me to learn React i tried it on the header, app (content) and footer. I don't know what else i have to include in my question because there's not much else to show.

Comment: Then, you kinda miss the purpose of React. It renders only to a virtual dom upon changes in state or props of the components, and only items that were actually changed would be rendered to the DOM. Thanks to the virtual DOM, I don't think you could really do a lot to improve performance. On the other side, thinking about performance optimization so early in the "game" can be very counter productive

Comment: Just as an extra info, I created this small [codepen](https://codepen.io/Icepickle/pen/mmoVxz). It should pretty much look like your html (that you still do not show, although probably the error is there). It shows both the single render, as the full render. Creating it as an App in React is imho lots more interesting since you don't have to handle state/prop changes throughout your app (React does this for you), so you can actually work on the functionality. Though, if you look at things like redux you could ofcourse bind on store changes